# standardUserDefaults reading problem

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I've got a problem similar to [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712519/getting-nil-from-standarduserdefaults)

I'm using XCode 3.2.4 (1708). After I reinstalled it, I'm started to get Nil from my NSUserDefaults object.

If I'm writing:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {    
 NSUserDefaults *sUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];    
 NSString *myAdd = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:kMyIPaddress];
 }
```

I get Nil in myAdd variable, but if I do like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
 NSUserDefaults *sUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [standardUserDefaults setObject:@"192.168.1.2" forKey:kMyIPaddress];
 NSString *myAdd = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:kMyIPaddress];
 }
```

I get 192.168.1.2 in myAdd object. So looks like UserDefaults stays empty before I put something to them, but they exists in General Preferences and contains proper values. Why can't I access them before I put something there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your default values with NSUserDefaults.

```
NSDictionary *def = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"192.168.1.2", kMyIPaddress,
                     nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:def];
```

and you need to do this every time your app starts.
It doesn't matter that there are settings in the Settings.app (my interpretation of your `General Preferences`). If those values are not changed manually they are not stored in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: But if I register defaults in the ViewDidLoad like that - Defaults will be overwritten with *def every time I launch the Application, right?

Comment: Looks like it don't overwrite settings, but just initialize them - that what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

after putting your NSString there?